# MySQL CONCAT: Add a comma/separator only when field is NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, concat-ws

To summarize, I have an update query that will tack on a string of data (e.g. SAVE15) to an existing field. Currently, I anticipate this field to already have some information in it so my values are appending as ", SAVE15" which is a comma and space separator. This works for now but soon I anticipate the need to insert a comma and space only if the field is NOT NULL. If it is null, I need it to insert "SAVE15". Here is my current query:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order sfo
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_grid sfog
ON sfog.entity_id = sfo.entity_id
SET sfo.coupon_code = concat(IFNULL(sfo.coupon_code, ""),", SAVE15")
WHERE sfog.increment_id = "12345678";
```

Here is my attempt to use CONCAT_WS to add a separator ony when necessary:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order sfo
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_grid sfog
ON sfog.entity_id = sfo.entity_id
SET sfo.coupon_code = CONCAT_WS(',',IFNULL(sfo.coupon_code, ""),"SAVE15")
WHERE sfog.increment_id = "12345678";
```

I thought it was working at first but then it inserted ",SAVE15" onto a null field. I believe the second query is the correct method but I seem to be using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `Concat_WS` tell us that it will skip any Null field but not an empty string.  You must therefore remove the call to `IfNull(sfo.coupon_code, "")` that convert the Null value into an empty string.

Comment: use `concat_ws(',' ,  sfo.coupon_code, ,"SAVE15") `